# Navigate new page in same tab/window using button

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to navigate a page to another page in the same window (web browser = Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer) using button. The steps are,

1. The page will popup message for confirmation.
2. If the user click ok, then the page will navigate to other page in the same tab/window.
3. If the user click cancel or x, it stays on the current page.

I have tried using

`window.open("home.php","_self");` and `window.location.href="home.php";` and `document.location.replace("home.php");` and `location.replace("home.php");` and `location.assign("home.php");`

but it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

```
        <span title="Click to register the new user"><button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Register User</button></span>
        <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    confirm("Proceed?");
                    window.open("home.php");
                }
        </script>
```

Comment: use `document.location.replace`

Comment: Ok, I have used `document.location.replace` and `location.replace`, but still won't work.

Comment: I just wonder, why don't you use <a href="home.php" class= "button"> click to bla bla </a>

Comment: @MaxmillonIce, what error do you get?

Comment: @EmilReñaEnriquez ,  How do you popup msg by using <a href ?

Comment: @Arvind , wasn't error. It's just...it won't navigate to other page. It reloads the current page, I think..

Comment: @MaxmillonIce, what are those pages, can you name them ?

Comment: @MaxmillonIce <a href="home.php" onclick="confirm('Proceed?')"> click me </a>

Comment: @EmilReñaEnriquez , not a link but button.

Comment: @MaxmillonIce you asked me how do you popup msg by using href, I answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to me is, possibly you are using `form` with `button` which leads to reload.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Register User</button>
```

Make the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Also major browser do have popup blocker enabled where this line may fail `window.open("home.php")`;

Small change in script as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
   if(confirm("Proceed?")) //<--- ok/yes = true, no/cancel/close = false
      location.href = "home.php";
}
```

Small demo:

```js
var ask = function() {
  if (confirm('Proceed ?'))
    location.href = "http://espn.go.com/";
};
```

```html
<button onclick="ask();">Watch ...</button>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `form` with `button`. No wonder! So, I've changed `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and it works! Also, `location.href` . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href
```

is not a function . You have to use it as

```
window.location.href="home.php";
```

Updated your code and this works

```html
<span title="Click to register the new user"><button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Register User</button></span>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
       
       if( confirm("Proceed?") )
        window.location.href="home.php";
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry. I typed it wrong. And yes, I did that and it still won't work.

Comment: I have done that by copy&paste your code but still, it doesn't work.